# Python - invalid character in identifier error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code in a file called script.py

```
import json
myjson=json.loads(open(‘id.json’,’rb’))
    [(os.makedirs(os.path.join(*v.split(‘_’))), open(os.path.join(*v.split(‘_’),‘id.txt’),’w’).write(k)) for k,v in myjson.items()]
```

I also have in the same folder, a file called id.json that looks like this:

```
{
"0":"text_test",
"1":"text_text",
"2":"test_test",
...
}
```

But when I try to run py script.py command on the cmd, I get this error :

```
  File "script.py", line 2
    myjson=json.loads(open(‘id.json’,’rb’))
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

I am not very familiar with Python and some guides from the web didn't help me out.

Comment: pure supposition but I think that id.json is a file name that you can't give to your file

Comment: replace `‘` with `'` or `"` and do not use mixed `‘_’` - you got the wrong string delimiters

Comment: Are they quotes only ```'```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quote you are using is invalid.

You are using: `‘`

You have to use: `"`   or `'`

Replace all of your `‘` with `'`

Comment: it worked , but now i get this error: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not BufferedReader